# Liquid question - access to value in array

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have following liquid code :

{% assign maxVersionNumber = Data.Callout.ResponseBody.invoiceFiles | sort: "versionNumber" | last %}

{ % assign pdfURL = maxVersionNumber[1] %}

WIth this :
maxVersionNumber        {3}
id  :   c7c312c104934fe09736b4d53403dc72
pdfFileUrl  :   /v1/files/8adc98ad870e3c0101870f10218520a7
versionNumber   :   16795849270242023-03-23T15:22:07.024Z

I expect the code { % assign pdfURL = maxVersionNumber[1] %} to give me back :
pdfFileUrl  :   /v1/files/8adc98ad870e3c0101870f10218520a7

But I got nothing

Any suggestion please ?

Comment: Are you sure `maxVersionNumber ` has something in the first place?

Comment: Yes , example ==> maxVersionNumber  {3}
id : 0c54d19e55034173afcf37492cd454ae
pdfFileUrl : /v1/files/8adc98ad870e3c0101870f1009c2207d
versionNumber : 16795849208622023-03-23T15:22:00.862Z
it should send me back ==>                                                       pdfFileUrl : /v1/files/8adc98ad870e3c0101870f1009c2207d

Comment: Sorry can you check how to format question? It's really hard to understand what's happening

Comment: I found it , in fact maxVersionNumber {3}  is an object and not an array so I should write : maxVersionNumber.pdfFileUrl